# Angular. Form control values from subscription

Tags: angular, forms, subscription

I have a form which has to look like this:
[image]
Values of **userGroups** are taken from Web Api and here I faced a problem.
I implement function that uses subscription and gets User Groups from http. Form is created in the constructor. In this case (obviously) the value of **userGroups** is undefined because it was assigned in subscription.

```
export class UserAddComponent implements OnInit {
userForm: FormGroup;
userGroups: UserGroup[];

constructor(
    private http: HttpService,
    private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.userForm = fb.group({
            'login': ['', [Validators.required]],
            'userGroups': this.fb.array(this.userGroups.map(x => !1)) // userGroups is undefined
        });
    }

    private getUserGroups() {
        this.http.get<ODataResponse>(`${this.soddApiUrl}/UserGroups`)
            .subscribe({
                next: (data: ODataResponse) => {
                    this.userGroups = <UserGroup[]>data.value;
                },
                error: () => { },
                complete: () => { }
            });
    }

    get login() { return this.userForm.get('login'); }
}
```

I tried another approach - to create form in subscription:

```
export class UserAddComponent implements OnInit {
userForm: FormGroup;
userGroups: UserGroup[];

constructor(
    private http: HttpService,
    private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.http.get<ODataResponse>(`${this.soddApiUrl}/UserGroups`)
            .subscribe({
                next: (data: ODataResponse) => {
                    this.userGroups = <UserGroup[]>data.value;

                    this.userForm = fb.group({
                        'login': ['', [Validators.required],
                        'userGroups': this.fb.array(this.userGroups.map(x => !1))
                    });
                },
                error: (err) => { },
                complete: () => { }
            });
    }
  
    get login() { return this.userForm.get('login'); } // userFrom is undefined
}
```

In this case form is created fine but I get **login** is undefined error in template (because **userForm** value was assigned in subscription).

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="addUser()">
<div>
    <label for="login" class="label">Login</label>
    <input type="text" nbInput fullWidth id="login" formControlName="login"
          <!-- login is undefined here -->
          [status]="login.dirty ? (login.invalid  ? 'danger' : 'success') : 'basic'"
          [attr.aria-invalid]="login.invalid && login.touched ? true : null" />
</div>

<div>
    <label class="label">User Groups</label>
    <div *ngFor="let userGroup of userGroups; let i = index" formArrayName="userGroups">
        <nb-checkbox [formControlName]="i">{{userGroup.Title}}</nb-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, in the first case I can't get access to array which values assigned in subscription, in the second case I can't get the value of form control because is is out of subscription.

Is there any solution to get it worked?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the form creation to OnInit method

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.createForm();
}

private createForm() {
    this.userForm = fb.group({
        'login': ['', [Validators.required]],
        'userGroups': this.fb.array((this.userGroups || []).map(x => !1)) // add empty array to avoid undefined error
    });
}
```

then in subscribed method call again the create form

```
yourHttpMethod() {
   this.http.get<ODataResponse>(`${this.soddApiUrl}/UserGroups`)
        .subscribe({
            next: (data: ODataResponse) => {
                this.userGroups = <UserGroup[]>data.value;

                this.createForm();
            },
            error: (err) => { },
            complete: () => { }
        });
}
```

if you can't lose the initial subscription then use the patchform in subscribe.

Comment: Thanks @LautaroLopezRuiz
Did it like this:
`ngOnInit(): void {
     this.createForm();
     this.getUserGroups(); // myHttpMethod()
}`